# integrate $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ in $\{x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2 = 1\}$

Tags: integration

How can I integrate $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ in $x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2 \leq 1$?

I most probably need to use spherical coordinates but I don't manage doing it.

Comment: Please use MathJax in order to format your question properly. You can have a look here for a tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

Changing coordinates $(x',y',z')=(x,y,z-1)$, you get
$$
I=\iiint_{x'^2+y'^2+z'^2\leq1}\frac{1}{x'^2+y'^2+(z'+1)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x'\,\mathrm{d}y'\,\mathrm{d}z'
$$
So spherical polars gives
\begin{align*}
I&=\int_0^1\int_0^\pi\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{r^2\sin\theta}{r^2+2r\cos\theta+1}\,\mathrm{d}\phi\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}r\\
&=2\pi\int_0^1\int_0^\pi\frac{r^2\sin\theta}{r^2+2r\cos\theta+1}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}r\\
&=\dots=2\pi
\end{align*}